# What is the formal definition of change of variable?

Tags: real-analysis, definition, change-of-variable

Change of variable is a very common and elementary technique in introductory mathematics. **But it  do know the formal definition of it**. First of all

> **What is the formal definition of variable in mathematics?**

Now, **What is the formal definition of change of variable in mathematics?**

What is the need of introducing a concept of change of variable in mathematics?

And is there any relation between change of variable and integration by substitution?

Comment: "is there any relation between change of variable and integration by substitution?" To substitute means to take out one thing and replace it with another. To change it, if you will. Yes, integration by substitution is one instance of change of variables.

Comment: @Arthur Is not the substitution theorem general than the change of variable because in change if variable in 1d we are taking invertible mapping?

Comment: Changing variable is not required to be invertible. There are times when invertibility is useful, but it isn't necessary. All that is needed is that every required value of the old variable must be obtainable from the new variable. And there is no "Formal definition" of change of variable, because changing variables is a technique, not a mathematical object. You express your old variable as some function of a new variable, then everywhere the old variable occurs in your expression, you replace it by the function of the new variable.

Comment: If you want to see a formal treatment of the concept and justification, you can look in pretty much any book about the foundations of mathematics. I personally found Bourbaki's *The Elements of Set Theory* enlightening, but it is highly formal, and a bit dated, now.